# Google Cloud: Auto update image used by container post auto build by trigger?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Is it possible to auto update image used by already deployed container post auto build by trigger?

One solution I know is to add command in cloud build.yaml for restarting the server.

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to restart the container with an updated image, as you cannot modify an image when the container is already deployed. If you need the latest image version to be consistently deployed, then just omit a specific version number for the image, the client defaults to latest. [More details here](https://docker-curriculum.com/).

If this is not the issue, please specify and provide some examples.